# Какие библиотеки будут нужны для реализации приложения под Android?

Tags: java, android

Знаю, что сам вопрос имеет аналоги, но не знаю как заголовок сформулировать иначе. Я-новичок, хочу создать простое приложение(нашел источники информации)-календарь.Со временем я хотел бы его улучшить(добавить новых функций по мере улучшения уровня знаний). Хотел бы узнать совет от опытных программистов. Начну с банальных вещей. базовая функция-при запуске приложения выводить на экран календарь(естесственно дизайн будет свой), далее планируется присобачить что-то типа заметок(дабы превратить его в  органайзер-записную книжку), в последствии хочу добавить возможность создавать на рабочем столе напоминания от этого приложения.
Какие дополнительные фреймворки и инструменты мне могут для этого понадобиться?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Любые библиотеки и фреймворки, которые помогут решить поставленную локальную задачу вашего проекта и которую у вас нет желания (возможностей) решать самому. Их тысячи, на все случаи жизни и какие могут понадобится именно вам не знает никто. *JodaTime* можно вспомнить, если речь идет о календаре.

Вообще, существуют подборки наиболее популярных библиотек с кратким описанием, вроде [этой](https://github.com/fleveque/awesome-awesomes) . Вам нужны разделы [Java](https://github.com/akullpp/awesome-java) и [Android](https://github.com/JStumpp/awesome-android). (на самом деле таких сборников много и в части Android наиболее популярен [Android Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/)). Смотрите, читайте, выбирайте, запоминайте на будущее - будет ли лучше что то делать самому или использовать готовое решение.

Так же не надо забывать о [библиотеках поддержки Google](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html).